# $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ is a subspace of the vector space of all $4\times 4$ matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ denote the set of all matrices $X$ satisfying
$$X^TM+MX=0$$

How can I show that $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ is a vector subspace of the vector space of all $4\times 4$ matrices?

---

I think the only property that I need to worry about satisfying is closure, is this correct?

I mean that should follow from two $4\times 4$ matrices being multiplied together yielding another $4\times 4$ matrix. Perhaps there is an eigenvalue argument?

---

$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Travis I meant in the sense that $X^TM$ is also a $4\times 4$ matrix, and so is $MX$ and $X$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix

Comment: you should state explicitely the form of $M$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check that a subset $S$ of a vector space (over, say, the field $\mathbb{F}$) is a vector subspace, we need only check:

1. That the subset is nonempty ($S \neq \varnothing$).
2. That the subset is closed under scalar multiplication (for all $f \in \mathbb{F}$, $s \in S$, we have $fs \in S$).
3. That the subset is closed under addition (for all $s_1, s_2 \in S$, we have $s_1 + s_2 \in S$).